# Angular Directive template throw an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

I have some problem in angular directive templating.

```
'use strict';

 function HomeDirective() {
  return {
    controller: 'homeController',
    template: require('./views/home.html'),

    restrict: 'AEC',
    scope: true
  }
}

module.exports = HomeDirective;
```

I have a template in views folder.My views is

```
<div>
<p>This is Home Page.You can nevigate to any page</p>
<p>The Content is {{test}}</p>
</div>
```

The error is following

```
<div>                                                                           
  ^                                                                               
ParseError: Unexpected token                                                        
at wrapWithPluginError (C:\Users\DAT-Asset-110\Desktop\Test 
Code\anguler_test_structure\node_modules\gulp-browserify\index.js:44:10)
```

It is working when i use

```
'use strict';

 function HomeDirective() {
    return {
    controller: 'homeController',

   template: '<div><p>This is Home Page.You can nevigate to any page</p>
   <p>The Content is {{test}}</p></div>',
    restrict: 'AEC',
    scope: true
  }
 }

 module.exports = HomeDirective;
```

Can anyone help me.what is the problem and what is the solution of it?

Comment: Are you using webpack to load your template ? . if not then it should be templateUrl not template .

Comment: Can you send the proper link step of using webpack.I use browserify.@ShushanthPallegar

Answer (score 1):

Use templateUrl instead of template: `templateUrl: 'views/home.html'`

```
'use strict';

 function HomeDirective() {
  return {
    controller: 'homeController',
    templateUrl: 'views/home.html',

    restrict: 'AEC',
    scope: true
  }
}

module.exports = HomeDirective;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.what is the problem when i am using template instead of templateUrl @Syed

Comment: is `require('./views/home.html'),` a function that return the html ?

Comment: check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923630/how-to-use-both-gulp-babel-and-gulp-browserify